# Values Are not updating or added to Redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a list with checkboxes (Material-UI)

and I want the values (topping(array of max three toppings), toppingPrice(0.50 for every added topping)
to my components state 
and then dispatch my action (ADD_TOPPING) 
and see in my redux state the updating values(topping, toppingPrice)

I'm importing my **action** creator

```
export const ADD_TOPPING = 'ADD_TOPPING'
    export function addTopping(pizza) {
      return {
        type: ADD_TOPPING,
        payload: pizza
      }
    }
```

into my **component**

```
class CheckboxList extends React.Component {


  state = {
    topping:[],
    toppingPrice:0,
    checked: [0],

  };

  shouldDisableCheckbox = value => {
     const maxAllowed = 4
     const { checked } = this.state
     return checked.length >= maxAllowed && checked.lastIndexOf(value) === -1
  }


  handleToggle = value => () => {
    const { checked } = this.state;
    const currentIndex = checked.indexOf(value);
    const newChecked = [...checked];
    this.setState({
      topping: value[0],
      toppingPrice: parseFloat(value[1]),

     });
    if (currentIndex === -1) {
      newChecked.push(value);
    } else {
      newChecked.splice(currentIndex, 1);
    }

    this.setState({
      checked: newChecked,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const toppings = ['Chicken', 'Pineapple', 'Corn', 'Olives (green)', 'Red union', 'Spinach', 'Cherry tomatoes']
      console.log(this.state)
    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <h3>Additional Toppings <br/><small>(€ 0.50 Per Topping)</small></h3>
        <List>
          {toppings.map(value => (
            <ListItem
              key={value}
              role={undefined}
              dense
              button
              onClick={this.handleToggle(value)}
              className={classes.listItem}
              disabled={this.shouldDisableCheckbox(value)
              }

            >
              <Checkbox
                checked={this.state.checked.indexOf(value) !== -1}
                tabIndex={-1}
                disableRipple

              />
              <ListItemText primary={`NewAge ${value}`} />

            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

CheckboxList.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
  return {pizza: state.pizza}
}
const Connect = connect(mapStateToProps, {addTopping})(CheckboxList)


export default withStyles(styles)(Connect);
```

and connecting it to my **reducer**

```
import { ADD_TOPPING} from '../actions/pizza_config'

const initialState = {
  topping: [],
  toppingPrice: 0,
}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  const updateState = {...state}
  switch (action.type) {
  case ADD_TOPPING:

    if(action.payload.topping){
      return updateState.topping = action.payload.topping
    }
    if(action.payload.toppingPrice){
    return  updateState.toppingPrice = action.payload.toppingPrice
    }else{
      return {...state}
    }


  default:
    return state
  }
}
```

I have very similar code for 
comparable components
that do update state locally and appear in the redux state etc.

I would like it to update the array in my redux state and add 0.50 for every checked topping

but after three hours of breaking my head
I can't seem to figure it out.
how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are passing a single object, rather than using mapDispatchToProps for your connect function.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = () => {
  return {
    onToppingAdded: (topping) => actions.addTopping(topping),
  }
}
```

Then make your export be:

```
const Connect = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CheckboxList)
```

Your reducer also seems to have a problem.

```
  case ADD_TOPPING:

if(action.payload.topping){
  **return updateState.topping = action.payload.topping**
}
if(action.payload.toppingPrice){
return  updateState.toppingPrice = action.payload.toppingPrice
}else{
  return {...state}
}
```

Since the payload will have both a topping and a topping price, but you are returning right after updating only the first part.
Refactor this to immutably update all of the relevant info, and then return your updated state all at once.

I would also recommend you setup the redux dev tools. You'll be able to see what actions are happening, as well as what the redux store is. [See instructions here](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension)

As a general note - I suggest you handle your entire pizza in redux, rather than splitting it between the react state & redux store as you have it now.

When using Redux, the only time I use the react state is for local UI state. So the checkbox is fine to stay in the container, but you can put everything else into redux.

I am pretty sure your problem is entirely in the reducer right now, but if you fix that logic and you are still having issues, post a codepen and I'll take a closer look.